# Mostrar Consultas con ORM agrupados por un campo y SUM por cada TIPO en DJANGO

Tags: python, django, orm

Muy buenas, tengo registros en mi BASE de DATOS en POSTGRES y desde ORM de django intento hacer una consulta:  Cada registro tiene un campo COSTO y TIPO, y puede haber N registro de un solo tipo con distintos precios.
Lo que quiero es traer, la sumatoria de los COSTOS AGRUPADO por TIPOS; como se puede ver en la Imagen, tengo en la Base de datos 6 registros y agrupados me arrojaría solo 3 registros con su SUMATORIA respectiva.
He intentado hacer con ANNOTATE y SUM pero sin éxito, como se puede hacer de forma eficiente la consulta? gracias

[image: Explicaccion grafica de uns consulta con ORM en DJANGO]

Intente hacer así

```
consulta = Venta.objects.all().annotate(totalp=Sum(F('costo'), 
           output_field=models.FloatField()))
```

Pero no me trae agrupado

Comment: Hola, tal vez puedas mostrar lo que estás intentando para poder ayudarte

Comment: Que información le puedo facilitar?, bueno en realidad mi DB tiene muchos campos, solo quiero con ese esquema que pueda REALIZAR al consulta por ejemplo un con nombre FICTICIO, digamos MI_TABLA...

Comment: Alejandro, me refiero a la parte en la cual estás tratando de armar el query (a través del ORM de Django)

Comment: Bueno intente hacer asi: `consulta = Venta.objects.all().annotate(totalp=Sum(F('costo'), output_field=models.FloatField()))`  pero requiero agrupar por TIPO asi como esta lo suma todo

Comment: podrias agregar que intentastes? asi es baja calidad tu pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Un poco tarde la respuesta :P

```
 consulta = Venta.objects.all().values('tipo')
            .annotate(totalp=Sum(F('costo'),
             output_field=models.FloatField()))
```

Saludos, si es que aún lees esto.